# Optimizing SQL Query for max value with various conditions from a single MySQL table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `sensor_data` AS `sd1`
    WHERE  (sd1.timestamp BETWEEN '2017-05-13 00:00:00'
                              AND '2017-05-14 00:00:00')
      AND  (`id` = 
            (
                SELECT  `id`
                    FROM  `sensor_data` AS `sd2`
                    WHERE  sd1.mid = sd2.mid
                      AND  sd1.sid = sd2.sid
                    ORDER BY  `value` DESC, `id` DESC
                    LIMIT  1)
           )
```

**Background:**

I've [checked the validity of the query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html) by changing `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT 0`, and the query works without any problem. However with `LIMIT 1` the query doesn't complete, it just states `loading` until I shutdown and restart.

**Breaking the Query down:**

I have broken down the query with the date boundary as follows:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `sensor_data` AS `sd1`
    WHERE  (sd1.timestamp BETWEEN '2017-05-13 00:00:00'
                              AND '2017-05-14 00:00:00')
```

This takes about 0.24 seconds to return the query with 8200 rows each having 5 columns.

**Question:**

I suspect the second half of my Query, is not correct or well optimized. 
The tables are as follows:

**Current Table:**

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----------------------+
|  id  |  mid  |  sid  |  v  |       timestamp       |
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----------------------+
|  51  |  10   |   1   |  40 |  2015-05-13 11:56:01  |
|  52  |  10   |   2   |  39 |  2015-05-13 11:56:25  |
|  53  |  10   |   2   |  40 |  2015-05-13 11:56:42  |
|  54  |  10   |   2   |  40 |  2015-05-13 11:56:45  |
|  55  |  10   |   2   |  40 |  2015-05-13 11:57:01  |
|  56  |  11   |   1   |  50 |  2015-05-13 11:57:52  |
|  57  |  11   |   2   |  18 |  2015-05-13 11:58:41  |
|  58  |  11   |   2   |  19 |  2015-05-13 11:58:59  |
|  59  |  11   |   3   |  58 |  2015-05-13 11:59:01  |
|  60  |  11   |   3   |  65 |  2015-05-13 11:59:29  |
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----------------------+
```

**Q:** How would I get the `MAX(v)`for each `sid` for each `mid`?
***NB#1:*** In the example above `ROW` `53`, `54`, `55` have all the same value (`40`), but I would like to retrieve the row with the most recent timestamp, which is `ROW` `55`.

**Expected Output:**

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----------------------+
|  id  |  mid  |  sid  |  v  |       timestamp       |
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----------------------+
|  51  |  10   |   1   |  40 |  2015-05-13 11:56:01  |
|  55  |  10   |   2   |  40 |  2015-05-13 11:57:01  |
|  56  |  11   |   1   |  50 |  2015-05-13 11:57:52  |
|  58  |  11   |   2   |  19 |  2015-05-13 11:58:59  |
|  60  |  11   |   3   |  65 |  2015-05-13 11:59:29  |
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----------------------+
```

**Structure of the table:**

[image]

***NB#2:***
*Since this table has over 110 million entries, it is critical to have have date boundaries, which limits to ~8000 entries over a 24 hour period.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query can be written as follows:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.mid, t1.sid, t1.v, t1.ts
FROM yourtable t1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT mid, sid, MAX(v) as v 
            FROM yourtable
        WHERE ts BETWEEN '2015-05-13 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-14 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY mid, sid
    ) t2
    ON  t1.mid = t2.mid
    AND t1.sid = t2.sid
    AND t1.v   = t2.v
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT mid, sid, v, MAX(ts) as ts
            FROM yourtable
        WHERE ts BETWEEN '2015-05-13 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-14 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY mid, sid, v
    ) t3
    ON  t1.mid = t3.mid
    AND t1.sid = t3.sid
    AND t1.v   = t3.v
    AND t1.ts  = t3.ts;
```

---

**Edit and Explanation:**

The first sub-query (first `INNER JOIN`) fetches `MAX(v)` per `(mid, sid)` combination. The second sub-query is to identify `MAX(ts)` for every `(mid, sid, v)`. At this point, the two queries do not influence each others' results. It is also important to note that `ts` date range selection is done in the two sub-queries independently such that the final query has fewer rows to examine and no additional `WHERE` filters to apply.

Effectively, this translates into getting `MAX(v)` per `(mid, sid)` combination initially (first sub-query); and if there is more than one record with the same value `MAX(v)` for a given `(mid, sid)` combo, then the excess records get eliminated by the selection of `MAX(ts)` for every `(mid, sid, v)` combination obtained by the second sub-query. We then simply associate the output of the two queries by the two `INNER JOIN` conditions to get to the `id` of the desired records.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OUD90830)

Comment: I saw a comment before (which is now deleted) about wanting to add date range checks, but I couldn't reply then. If you were to add a `WHERE` condition for date range check, I'd recommend doing so in the subquery. As an aside, any `ORDER BY` should be a part of the main query (adding it in subquery would usually be futile).

Comment: I'll also need the row with the _most recent_ `timestamp` which meet these conditions, for further clarification please have a read of  ___NB#1___. I have changed the sample table by adding rows 54 and 55.

Comment: @3kstc Please tell me if I'm wrong, but isn't this technically equivalent to then possibly having two exactly same `max(v)` for a given `(mid, sid)` pair, but recorded into the table with different timestamps?

Comment: that is correct... the `id` would  be unique as it is a `primary key`, we could use something like the `max(id)`  for a corresponding  `max(v)` for a given `(mid ,sid)` pair.

Comment: @3kstc Please check the edit. If the table is indexed properly, hopefully the revised query should produce the expected results in a reasonable time.

Comment: @DhrubSaxena, that's brilliant! The query time is so quick <0.1s! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

select * from sensor_data s1 where s1.v in (select max(v) from sensor_data s2 group by s2.mid)

union

select * from sensor_data s1 where s1.v in (select max(v) from sensor_data s2 group by s2.sid);

Answer (score 0):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` does not optimize well.  It is even worse because of being correlated.

What you are looking for is a [*groupwise-max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) .

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to know at least what the `PRIMARY KEY` is.

**Suggested code**

You will need:

- With the `WHERE`: `INDEX(timestamp, mid, sid, v, id)`
- Without the `WHERE`: `INDEX(mid, sid, v, timestamp, id)`

Code:

```
SELECT id, mid, sid, v, timestamp
    FROM ( SELECT @prev_mid := 99999,   -- some value not in table
                  @prev_sid := 99999,
                  @n := 0 ) AS init
    JOIN (
             SELECT  @n := if(mid != @prev_mid OR
                              sid != @prev_sid,
                              1, @n + 1) AS n,
                     @prev_mid := mid,
                     @prev_sid := sid,
                     id, mid, sid, v, timestamp
                 FROM sensor_data
                 WHERE timestamp >= '2017-05-13'
                       timestamp  < '2017-05-13' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                 ORDER BY mid DESC, sid DESC, v DESC, timestamp DESC
         ) AS x
    WHERE n = 1
    ORDER BY mid, sid;   -- optional
```

Notes:

- The index is 'composite' and 'covering'.
- This should make one pass over the index, thereby providing 'good' performance.
- The final `ORDER BY` is optional; the results *may* be in reverse order.
- All the `DESC` in the *inner* `ORDER BY` must be in place to work correctly (unless you are using MySQL 8.0).
- Note how the `WHERE` avoids including both midnights?  And avoids manually computing leap-days, year-ends, etc?
- With the `WHERE` (and associated `INDEX`), there will be filtering, but a 'sort'.
- Without the `WHERE` (and the other `INDEX`), sort will not be needed.

You can test the performance of any competing formulations via this trick, even if you do not have enough rows (yet) to get reliable timings:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

This can also be used to compare different versions of MySQL and MariaDB -- I have seen 3 significantly different performance characteristics in a related groupwise-max test.

Comment: I've placed my screenshot, the `PRIMARY KEY` is the `id`

Comment: is there anything else I can give you from my end to optimise the search query?

Comment: I have tried implementing the _groupwise-max_ but I am seriously [struggling](http://rextester.com/OBCR24311) :( Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Oh, I see the struggle.  Looks like a case that that link does not easily cover.